# MySQL Question (joins)

Tags: mysql, join, multiple-tables

I'm not that into MySQL joins, so maybe you could give me a hand. I've got the following tables:

```
Table a  
Fields ID,name

Table b  
Fields aID,cID,ID,found

Table c  
Fields ID,name
```

The result I want to get is the following: I want all the records where b.found = 1. Of these records I don't want a.id or a.name, but I want the number of records that would have been returned if I would have wanted so. So if there are five records that have b.found = 1 and c.id = (for example) 3, then I want a returned value of 5, c.id and c.name.

Someone is able to do this?

Actually this is what I want to get from the database:
A list of all records in table C and a count of records in table B that has found = 1 and b.c_id = c.id

Comment: So you want c.id, c.name and a count of the records matching from a?

Comment: I think you want to group by c.id right?

Comment: Could you post the actual field names for table b, as they can not be referenced by their position in the other tables within it: `c.id`, `a.id` for instance.

Comment: Use the table structure from my (wrong) answer. It makes more sense

Comment: I'm using that table structure right know, I just give it another name than you did, c_id or cID doesn't make a difference for the working of the Query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Table: a
Fields: ID, name

Table: b
Fields: aID, cID, found

Table: c
Fields: ID, name



SELECT c.ID, c.name, COUNT(1)
FROM b
JOIN c ON c.ID = b.cID AND b.found=1
GROUP BY c.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(*)
    FROM c
        INNER JOIN b
            ON c.id = b.c_id
                AND b.found = 1
    GROUP BY c.id, c.name
```

Comment: I think I agree with you. I'm still not sure I understand the requirements

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(*), c.id, c.name
FROM a, b, c
WHERE a.id = b.a.id AND c.id = b.a.id AND b.found = 1 AND c.id = idThatIAmSearchingFor

Apologies if I didn't get the syntax exact, but I believe that's the basic structure you want.  The COUNT function returns the number of rows found by the query.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT count(`c`.*), 
           `c`.`id`, 
          `c`.`name` 
  FROM `b` 
  JOIN `c` 
    ON `c`.`id` = `b`.`c_id` 
 WHERE `b.found` = 1
```

Comment: NOT WORKING: Gives a mysql error, (COUNT(c.*) isn't working I guess)

Answer (score 0):

I think this would provide the required output -

```
select count(*), b.cID, c.name from b
inner join c on c.id=b.cID and b.found=1
group by b.cID
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count, c.id, c.name
FROM b join a on a.id = b.a_id
WHERE b.found = 1
GROUP BY c.Id;

COUNT returns count of records in each group from GROUP BY.

Comment: NOT WORKING: SQL doesn't recognise columns from table c